# .Net Core 3 Mysql Pomelo DateTime Incompatibility

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I want to get any data between two dates with .Net Core 3.1.3 Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v3.1.1

When I try with C# datetime no data returns:

```
SELECT * FROM Availability where (StartDate >= '26.03.2020 00:43:47' And StartDate <= '26.03.2020 00:43:47') or (EndDate <= '26.06.2020 00:43:47' And EndDate <= '26.06.2020 00:43:47')
```

But I try Mysql datetime returns some data:

```
SELECT * FROM Availability where (StartDate >= '2020-03-26 00:43:47' And StartDate <= '2020-03-26 00:43:47') or (EndDate <= '2020-06-26 00:43:47' And EndDate <= '2020-06-26 00:43:47')
```

My C# codes:

```
prop => prop.Availabilities.Any(o => (o.StartDate <= model.StartDate && o.StartDate >= model.StartDate) || (o.EndDate <= model.EndDate && o.EndDate >= model.EndDate))
```

What i can do on .Net Core codes?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing (what are those first two queries?) but see the following part of your query: `o.StartDate <= model.StartDate && o.StartDate >= model.StartDate` – The date can only be lower-equal **and** greater-equal to another date if both dates are equal. So this means `o.StartDate == model.StartDate` which is likely not what you want here. What is it that you want to query for?

Comment: I want to get data between two dates with .net core linq expression or linq. First two query is mysql query which is incompability date format.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following code, that demonstrates how to use `System.DateTime` in EF Core, and works without issues:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BestServedBefore { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So61433252",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.20-mysql"))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>()
                .HasData(
                    new IceCream
                    {
                        IceCreamId = 1,
                        Name = "Vanilla",
                        BestServedBefore = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30)
                    },
                    new IceCream
                    {
                        IceCreamId = 2,
                        Name = "Chocolate",
                        BestServedBefore = new DateTime(2020, 5, 1)
                    }
                );
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                // This code will work with *any* current culture, because EF Core and
                // Pomelo don't use the current culture for DateTime formatting.
                // Demonstrated here by explicitly setting the German culture.
                // This is of course *not necessary* and just for demonstration
                // puroposes.
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");

                // The following two queries use both, a literal `DATETIME`
                // value and a `System.DateTime` parameter.
                var today = DateTime.Today;

                var badIceCreams = context.IceCreams
                    .Where(i => i.BestServedBefore <= new DateTime(2020, 5, 6) ||
                                i.BestServedBefore <= today)
                    .ToList();

                var isAnyIceCreamBad = context.IceCreams
                    .Any(i => i.BestServedBefore <= new DateTime(2020, 5, 6) ||
                              i.BestServedBefore <= today);

                Debug.Assert(badIceCreams.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(badIceCreams[0].IceCreamId == 2);
                Debug.Assert(isAnyIceCreamBad == true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It generates the following SQL statementes:

```sql
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE DATABASE `So61433252`;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (24ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `BestServedBefore` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      );

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `BestServedBefore`, `Name`)
      VALUES (1, '2020-06-05 00:00:00', 'Vanilla');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      INSERT INTO `IceCreams` (`IceCreamId`, `BestServedBefore`, `Name`)
      VALUES (2, '2020-05-01 00:00:00', 'Chocolate');

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[@__today_0='2020-05-06T00:00:00' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT `i`.`IceCreamId`, `i`.`BestServedBefore`, `i`.`Name`
      FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
      WHERE (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= '2020-05-06 00:00:00') OR (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= @__today_0)

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__today_0='2020-05-06T00:00:00' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

      SELECT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM `IceCreams` AS `i`
          WHERE (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= '2020-05-06 00:00:00') OR (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= @__today_0))
```

As you can see, even though we explicitly set the current culture to `de-DE` (which uses the `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` date format), the `System.DateTime` value is still correctly formated using the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format:

```sql
WHERE (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= '2020-05-06 00:00:00')
```

However, because you would normally use variables to filter the date, those variables would be translated to parameters, so in practice your queries will not contain any `DATETIME` literals at all, but only parameter references. This can be seen in the sample code using the `today` variable, that translates to the following SQL fragment:

```sql
OR (`i`.`BestServedBefore` <= @__today_0)
```

Finally, you can see that an `Any()` LINQ query translates to a `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...)` SQL query, which is different from the one you have shown in your question.

So it looks like you might be doing something very fundamentally wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, your query is likely not what you want:

```
prop => prop.Availabilities.Any(o =>
    (o.StartDate <= model.StartDate && o.StartDate >= model.StartDate) ||
    (o.EndDate <= model.EndDate && o.EndDate >= model.EndDate))
```

This will requiere `o.StartDate` to be lower-equal to `model.StartDate` **and** `o.StartDate` to be bigger-equal to `model.StartDate`. This effectively means that `o.StartDate` is required to be equal to `model.StartDate`. The same applies to `EndDate` too. So the effective query that you are running is this:

```
prop => prop.Availabilities.Any(o =>
    (o.StartDate == model.StartDate) ||
    (o.EndDate == model.EndDate))
```

That’s very likely not what you want. Instead, if you want to check for items *between* your dates, you should do it like this:

```
prop => prop.Availabilities.Any(o =>
    o.StartDate >= model.StartDate && o.EndDate <= model.EndDate)
```

So now you look for items where `o.StartDate` is on or *after* `model.StartDate` **and** where `o.EndDate` is on or *before* `model.EndDate`. This makes `model.StartDate` and `model.EndDate` a range in which the availability needs to fit.

Comment: You are focusing wrong section of my problem poke. My problem is not expressions. C# datetime format is 26.04.2020 (dd.MM.yyyy). But mysql db only accepts yyyy-MM-dd format. So my query doesn't work with Pomelo MySQL provider. What can i do to get data with C# Linq expression?

Comment: If you use EntityFramework Core, and your model’s `StartDate` and `EndDate` are `DateTime` objects, then EF will take care of making sure that the resulting query is correct.

Comment: Yes I use EF Core. Then try it please. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v3.1.1